# How to import a custom EventEmitter and avoid TS Error: 2339?

Tags: typescript

I'm currently working on configuring a project with TypeScript on top of a boilerplate made in vanilla JavaScript. My issue arises during TS compilation in a preLaunchTask. I'm unable to access the 'report' property on a custom EventEmitter I'm importing locally. Here are the following errors from TS:

```
error TS2339: Property 'report' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter'.
```

Below is the *testing.ts* file:

```
'use strict';

import cors from 'cors';
import fs from 'fs';
import runner from '../../test-runner';
import express from 'express';

export default function (app: express.Application) {

  app.route('/_api/server.js')
    .get(function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function) {
      console.log('requested');
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/server.js', function (err, data) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(data.toString());
      });
    });
  app.route('/_api/routes/api.js')
    .get(function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function) {
      console.log('requested');
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/routes/api.js', function (err, data) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.type('txt').send(data.toString());
      });
    });
  app.route('/_api/controllers/convertHandler.js')
    .get(function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function) {
      console.log('requested');
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/controllers/convertHandler.js', function (err, data) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.type('txt').send(data.toString());
      });
    });

  var error;
  app.get('/_api/get-tests', cors(), function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next) {
    console.log(error);
    if (!error && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') return next();
    res.json({ status: 'unavailable' });
  },
    function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: Function) {
      if (!runner.report) return next();
      res.json(testFilter(runner.report, req.query.type, req.query.n));
    },
    function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
      runner.on('done', function (report) {
        process.nextTick(() => res.json(testFilter(runner.report, req.query.type, req.query.n)));
      });
    });
  app.get('/_api/app-info', function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    var hs = Object.keys(res.header)
      .filter(h => !h.match(/^access-control-\w+/));
    var hObj = {};
    hs.forEach(h => { hObj[h] = res.header[h] });
    delete res.header['strict-transport-security'];
    res.json({ headers: hObj });
  });

};

function testFilter(tests, type, n) {
  var out;
  switch (type) {
    case 'unit':
      out = tests.filter(t => t.context.match('Unit Tests'));
      break;
    case 'functional':
      out = tests.filter(t => t.context.match('Functional Tests') && !t.title.match('#example'));
      break;
    default:
      out = tests;
  }
  if (n !== undefined) {
    return out[n] || out;
  }
  return out;
}
```

And this is the test runner I'm attempting to import:

```
var analyser = require('./assertion-analyser');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var Mocha = require('mocha'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

var mocha = new Mocha();
var testDir = './tests'


// Add each .js file to the mocha instance
fs.readdirSync(testDir).filter((file) => {
    // Only keep the .js files
    return file.substr(-3) === '.js';

}).forEach((file) => {
    mocha.addFile(
        path.join(testDir, file)
    );
});

var emitter = new EventEmitter();  
emitter.run = () => {

  let tests = [];
  var context = "";
  var separator = ' -> ';
  // Run the tests.
  try {
  var runner = mocha.ui('tdd').run()
    .on('test end', (test) => {
        // remove comments
        var body = test.body.replace(/\/\/.*\n|\/\*.*\*\//g, '');
        // collapse spaces
        body = body.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
        var obj = {
          title: test.title,
          context: context.slice(0, -separator.length),
          state: test.state,
          body: body,
          assertions: analyser(body)
        };
        tests.push(obj);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        emitter.report = tests;
        emitter.emit('done', tests)
    })
    .on('suite', (s) => {
      context += (s.title + separator);

    })
    .on('suite end', (s) => {
      context = context.slice(0, -(s.title.length + separator.length))
    })
  } catch(e) {
    throw(e);
  }
};

module.exports = emitter;
```

And my *tsconfig.json* file as well:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowJs": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es6"
        ],
        "outDir": "public",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src",
    ]
}
```

I've attempted to narrow down my issue the best that I can, but I'm at a loss as to why the import and exports don't seem to be responding to one and other. I've been working out a lot of re-configuration errors lately, so my brain might be overthinking this. Please feel free to let me know if there's any other code that could be of use.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted my 'preLaunchTask' to match my TS compiler script name exactly - this wasn't the issue. The TypeScript error I was getting, that the 'report' property on my test runner was void, was due to older syntax in the test runner file that was due to the original test runner author assigning properties directly to an instance of the EventEmitter. To make the TS compiler happy I adjusted the test runner code to a class based setup instead, adding 'reports' to the constructor and thereby avoiding the 'void' or '() => void' return values from the original test runner.

**test-runner2.js**:

```
import analyser from '../../assertion-analyser';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

import Mocha from 'mocha';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { connect } from 'http2';

const mocha = new Mocha();
const testDir = './tests';

// Add each .js file to the mocha instance.
fs.readdirSync(testDir).filter(file => {
    return file.substr(-3) === '.js';
}).forEach(file => {
    mocha.addFile(
        path.join(testDir, file)
    );
});

class TestEmitter extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        this.report = []
    }

    run = () => {
        // Run the tests...
        let tests = [];
        let context = '';
        let separator = ' ~> ';

        try {
            const runner = mocha.ui('tdd').run()
                .on('test end', test => {
                    // remove comments
                    let body = test.body.replace(/\/\/.*\n|\/\*.*\\/g, '');
                    // collapse spaces
                    body = body.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                    const obj = {
                        title: test.title,
                        context: context.slice(0, -separator.length),
                        state: test.state,
                        body: body,
                        assertions: analyser(body)
                    };
                    tests.push(obj);
                })
                .on('end', () => {
                    emitter.report = tests;
                    emitter.emit('done', tests)
                })
                .on('suite', (s) => {
                  context += (s.title + separator);

                })
                .on('suite end', (s) => {
                  context = context.slice(0, -(s.title.length + separator.length))
                });
        } catch(err) {
            throw(err);
        }
    }
}

export default TestEmitter;
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowJs": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es6"
        ],
        "outDir": "public",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src",
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else trying to add TS to a vanilla JS boilerplate. I posted my config file as well. Using a `class` that `extends` the Node `EventEmitter` default class.